# How do I pull 1% of the rows in the dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a value to 1% of the data that exists in the dataframe.  How do I do that?

I have used manual approach by using `df.head(value)` and I don't think that this would be an ideal approach.

Is there any way we can do this dynamically as I am still new to this.

Comment: Use [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)